I can't seem to resolve this issue: ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy:
I'm trying to run a simple script that imports NumPy and pandas. When I run my script I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/***/***/***/***.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError( ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: numpy:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.11 from "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3"   * The NumPy version is: "1.23.4"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect. Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e' or 'arm64'))

I tried running this in one of my conda environments and in my base environemnts. Both have Python3.11 and NumPy 1.23.4 installed. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling NumPy.
I recently went through issues because of upgrading to a MacBook M3 chip. I had to uninstall and reinstall anaconda. I am not sure if this is part of the issue.
Also for context, this is what I see when I run conda list --explicit in my iTerm2:
`# platform: osx-arm64
@EXPLICIT
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/blas-1.0-openblas.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/bzip2-1.0.8-h620ffc9_4.conda
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64/c-ares-1.19.1-h80987f9_0.conda
...`

This is what I get when I check my python version:
Python 3.11.0
My packages seem to be using the arm64 architechture so I am really confused with what is going on with this error message.
Also, for whatever reason, I am not running into these issues when running jupyter notebooks that also import NumPy and pandas...?
Update 4/11/24:
I used brew to upgrade Python and seemed to be experiecing a symlink issue (not sure if that matters for this problem). I ran brew link --overwrite python@3.11.
My python path is: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Also, I found this article of someone experiencing this issue trying to run a different file.
I tried their solution of specifying the architechture since I have both and it worked. I don't want to have to specify the arch every time. How do I avoid this? The command below is what worked:
arch -arm64 python my-file.py

try to reinstall Python and add Environment variables of the new path then restart your system.
